# Is Lord Ayyappa the Hindu God of growth?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, ayyappa

Certain websites like http://www.mythologydictionary.com/ mention that Ayyappa is the god of **growth** but I don't understand what type of **growth** is that. Wikipedia just says that he is an avatar of Shasta and is the son of Lord Shiva and Mohini.

Please explain what is Lord Ayyappa the god of. If he really is the god of **growth** please explain what the term **growth** means - is it mental, emotional or physical **growth** or is it all three?

Comment: "I have heard that **he** is the god of growth". Who is HE here?

Comment: **He** refers to Ayyappan.Many websites say what is written above about him.

Comment: Please edit your question as " Why Ayyappa is called as God of growth?" or something else.

Comment: where did you find that Ayyappa is the known as god of growth?

Comment: @VineetMenon many mythical websites like this:[link](http://www.mythologydictionary.com/)

Comment: Please give answer

Comment: @KVickneshvara It has no direct citations or references. Most probably a bogus site.

Comment: @VineetMenon So what is he god for?

Comment: honestly. I don't know. I have never heard/read something as specific as 'growth' being related to Ayyappa as wealth is related to Laxmi or Learning to Saraswati.

Comment: You should find on wikipedia for Lord Ayyappa.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I alredy have but they do not tell me who he is god of!